# How can show a pop up to application user writing C# code in a wpf project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm working on a wpf project and I wont to show a pop up with messagges to user when some events occur. I need to do this via code.
I'm trying to write some code like the one follows:

```
void Foo()
{
      Popup msgPopup = new Popup();
      TextBox tb = new TextBox();
      tb.AcceptsReturn = true;
      tb.Text = msgPopup + "\n";
      msgPopup.Child = tb;
      myWindow.myStackPanel.Children.Add(msgPopup);
      myWindow.myStackPanel.IsEnabled = true;
      myWindow.Activate();
      msgPopup.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

This code seems to have no effects. I have seen a lot of other discussion threads and posts on pop up in wpf and I found nothing can help me...
All I found is on using pop up via XAML.
Thanks.

Comment: `Popup` control is a child element you can use to pop some UI without rearranging your layout. Robert answer seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: if you find my answer useful, and it answers your question, i would appreciate if you mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer isn't helping me.

Comment: I need pop up appears and fades out after some second, letting user continue his job. The pop up have to come out of the stack panel lies in the bottom-right part of the window. Add ing to my code `msgPopup.IsOpen = true;` Pop is visible. Isn't still what I wont but is something more...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a snippet I used in one of the applications

```
    Window waitWindow = new Window { Height = 100, Width = 300,  WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None };
    waitWindow.Content = new TextBlock { Text = "Fetching Data", FontSize = 30, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };

    //open window
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate { waitWindow.ShowDialog(); }));

   //do something

    //close window
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
    {

        waitWindow.Close();

    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the above to have any visual effect you would need to set:

```
msgPopup.IsOpen = true;
```

You will also more than likely want to set:

```
msgPopup.StaysOpen = false;
```

The above will allow the Popup to close if another element is clicked. Otherwise you will need to close the popup somewhere else.

Here is your method with the two properties added:

```
void Foo()
    {
        Popup msgPopup = new Popup();
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.AcceptsReturn = true;
        tb.Text = msgPopup + "\n";
        msgPopup.Child = tb;
        myWindow.myStackPanel.Children.Add(msgPopup);
        myWindow.myStackPanel.IsEnabled = true;
        myWindow.Activate();
        msgPopup.IsEnabled = true;
        msgPopup.StaysOpen = false;
        msgPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

You may also want to just set the position of the Popup rather than adding it as a child to another element.